# Chrome inspector shows yellow border area, but no border value

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am debugging an email template and came across one button which has a bit too much spacing. The inspector marks it yellow which I believe is the border area, but the same time shows "-" at the border property.

What is that supposed to mean?

Is this a bug in Chrome or how can I interpret this?

[image]

*edit*

Full style:
[image]

*edit2*

When checking the inherited styles I have a top/bottom border of 30px (I put them there as a workaround for Outlook 2016 on Windows).

The interesting part is that the yelllow area is 15px. So half of the border seems to be accounted to the table and half to the td.

Comment: The TD must have some cell-padding at table level, can you put your entire css in Question.

Comment: Less of a CSS question, more of a Chrome question.  Hard to tell, the screenshot removes some of the relevant "computed" styles.  I tested (Chrome on Mac), and agree yellow is border (orange is margin, green is padding).  What happens when you manually set a value, does the spacing change?

Comment: indeed if that's a TD, do you have `border-collapse: collapse` on the `table` element? If not, that's likely where that spacing is coming from -

Comment: yes it's more a chrome question - once I figure out how the dev tools work in this case I should be able to debug the CSS.